# What movie involves ripping a woman's face off?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

**Description**

Woman lying on a bed, and a close-up is shown of her spider/web tattoo on her lower back. The tattoo appears to cut itself along the webbing and she writhes in pain. She then begins to scream as her face rips itself off.

**Other Information**

The scene I described I found on a GIF someone e-mailed me. It is a modern movie, most likely year 2000+. I do not know who the actress is. As it is a GIF and there is no sound, I can't tell if there is any narration. The actress is wearing what appears to be a black tank top/bra and black panties. The background scene is a dilapidated room. The bed she is on is a small white mattress with no sheets.

I would upload the GIF, but it is larger than 2 mb. I put the GIF (**WARNING:** NSFL content) in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/i/videos/tweet/778081767353909252?).

**Question**

What movie is that scene from?

Comment: Please remember to add warning to such content in the future. I have edited it for now.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Sorry, I forgot about sensitivity to gore. Noted and will remember that in future posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from the British horror film [Book of Blood](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1169809/combined) from 2009.

> The story centers on a paranormal expert who, while investigating a gruesome slaying, finds a house that is at the intersection of "highways" transporting souls to the afterlife.

It's one of the first scenes, where a young woman with a spider tattoo is abused and beaten in her bed by an unseen force and her face is ripped off while her parents frantically try to break in. The film was produced by Clive Barker and based on one of his stories. You can briefly see the scene in the trailer around 0:37 *[**Warning**: A Bit Graphic]*: